# React Router - The Address Bar Is Changing But Not Rendering The Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I Am Making A Search Functionality On My Website But Whenever I Type Something And Hit The Search Button The Address ( URL ) Changes But The Component Stays The Same And When I Refresh The Page After That The Component Appears On The Screen.

Here's A Picture Of What I Meant :

[URL CHANGES BUT COMPONENT IS SAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xraMf.png)

Here's A Picture After The Reload :

[Should Be Like This When I Hit The Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ec5mm.png)

There Was A Solution I Found That Changing From Browser Router To Router Works But That Seems To Give The Following Error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

**App.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Routes,
} from "react-router-dom";

import Header from "./Components/Layouts/Header";
import Footer from "./Components/Layouts/Footer";
import Home from "./Components/Home";
import ProductDetails from "./Components/Product/ProductDetails";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <div className="container container-fluid">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} exact />
            <Route path="/search/:keyword" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**History.js**

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

export default history;
```

**Header Component**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import history from "./history";

import Search from "./Search";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <nav className="navbar row">
        <div className="col-12 col-md-3">
          <div className="navbar-brand">
            <img src="./images/logo.png" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="col-12 col-md-6 mt-2 mt-md-0">
          <Search history={history} />
        </div>

        <div className="col-12 col-md-3 mt-4 mt-md-0 text-center">
          <button className="btn" id="login_btn">
            Login
          </button>

          <span id="cart" className="ml-3">
            Cart
          </span>
          <span className="ml-1" id="cart_count">
            2
          </span>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

**Search Component**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Search = ({ history }) => {
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState("");

  const searchHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (keyword.trim()) {
      history.push(`/search/${keyword}`);
    } else {
      history.push("/");
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={searchHandler}>
      <div className="input-group">
        <input
          type="text"
          id="search_field"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Enter Product Name ..."
          onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <div className="input-group-append">
          <button id="search_btn" className="btn">
            <i className="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

**Home Component**

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";

import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

import Pagination from "react-js-pagination";

import MetaData from "./Layouts/MetaData";

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getAllProducts } from "../Actions/productActions";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Product from "./Product/Product";
import Loader from "./Layouts/Loader";
import { useAlert } from "react-alert";

const Home = () => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const alert = useAlert();

  const { loading, products, error, productsCount, resultPerPage } =
    useSelector((state) => state.products);

  const { keyword } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      return alert.error(error);
    }
    dispatch(getAllProducts(keyword, currentPage));
  }, [dispatch, error, alert, keyword, currentPage]);

  function setCurrentPageNo(pageNumber) {
    setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          <MetaData title="Buy At Discount Price" />
          <h1 id="products_heading">Latest Products</h1>
          <section id="products" className="container mt-5">
            <div className="row">
              {products &&
                products.map((product) => (
                  <Product product={product} key={product._id} />
                ))}
            </div>
          </section>

          {resultPerPage <= productsCount && (
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
              <Pagination
                activePage={currentPage}
                itemsCountPerPage={resultPerPage}
                totalItemsCount={productsCount}
                onChange={setCurrentPageNo}
                nextPageText={"Next"}
                prevPageText={"Prev"}
                firstPageText={"First"}
                lastPageText={"Last"}
                itemClass="page-item"
                linkClass="page-link"
              />
            </div>
          )}
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**Action**

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
  ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST,
  ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCESS,
  ALL_PRODUCTS_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
  CLEAR_ERRORS,
} from "../Constants/productConstants";

// Get All Product ( ACTIONS )

export const getAllProducts =
  (keyword = "", currentPage = 1) =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST });
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        `/api/v1/products?keyword=${keyword}&page=${currentPage}`
      );
      dispatch({
        type: ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCESS,
        payload: data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: ALL_PRODUCTS_FAIL,
        payload: error.response.data.message,
      });
    }
  };

//  Product Details ( ACTIONS )

export const getProductDetails = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST });
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/product/${id}`);
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data.product,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload: error.response.data.message,
    });
  }
};

// Clearing eroor message
export const clearErrors = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: CLEAR_ERRORS });
};
```

Comment: What is your Home component ? that's the one been rendered in both case.

Comment: From your code, it seems that in your Search Component when the form is submitted you're only updating the value of the keyword value but not performing any re-rendering with the new data..  You should also be re-rendering the html with the new results

Comment: @Ivo I have included the home component above please check it once again

Comment: @Cypherjac Please See The Edited Components

Comment: use `Switch` instead of `Routes` to wrapping your `Route` components

Comment: @GhaderSalehi my react-router is version 6.0 up Switch cannot be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the useNavigate() hook instead of createBrowserHistory()

First import useNavigate

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
```

then just do this after importing

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

const searchHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (keyword.trim()) {
      navigate(`/search/${keyword}`);
    } else {
      navigate("/");
    }
  };
```